# XCode iOS Build Successful but not opening on [physical] device

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode14

I am running my React Native project on my iOS device through Xcode. The project is successfully compiling to the simulator and I am now trying to build to my physical device (iPhone XR, iOS 15.3.1). The connected device is showing in the list of destinations and after building, I am seeing 'build successful' but no application appears on the device. When switching between the simulator and the actual device I also adjusted the target iOS sdk to 15.3, updated the necessary build configurations (or so I believe) and even tried **removing** the following lines from my `Info.plist`, as I saw somewhere that the architecture could be a limitation:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Furthermore, I followed the [the following guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-your-app-in-simulator-or-on-a-device#) for building to a physical device and did the following:

- signed into my (developer account) iCloud in XCode (same as my device)
- selected a team under the 'Signing and Capabilities' section (both targets AND the project)
- selected the connected device from destinations
- changed the iOS version in deployment info and build settings (Build Settings > iOS deployment target > iOS 15.3, both targets AND the project)
- verified the device is registered under my developer account

The one detail I could not get passed is regarding developer mode on the device. Since the XR is iOS 15.3.1 and developer mode is only available on iOS 16+, I am not sure how I am to enable developer mode, if I need to and if this could be the issue.

**Another detail** is that after the build is successful, it says the application built to SDK iOS 16.2 in the build output, but I cannot find anywhere else in settings to adjust the build SDK and don't know why it is 16.2. See the screenshot below.

[build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4Q4.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this same issue and got it resolved. Not sure if the same steps will work for you but worth a shot! For reference, I am using an iPhone 6s for development that runs on iOS 15.x

1. Reboot your Mac and iPhone, unplug the iPhone
2. Delete the build folder in `/ios`
3. Delete DerivedData
4. On Your iPhone:

   - Go to Settings.
   - Navigate to General.
   - Scroll down and find Reset.
   - Tap on Reset Location & Privacy. This will reset the location and privacy settings, including the trust settings for computers.
5. Plug your iPhone in, you should be prompted to trust the computer
6. Build your app with `yarn ios --device` via the terminal
7. Fingers crossed it builds now!